# подключение .crt и ca-bundle к Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https

Получил сертификат от Comodo для своего Tomcat сервера.
В архиве 2 файла:
domain.ca-bundle
domain.crt

Закидываю .crt c помощью KeyStore Explorer в server.keystore

```
<Connector port="443" 
    maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" 
    enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" 
    scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
    keystoreFile="D:\domain.keystore" 
    SSLEnabled="true" keystorePass="myPass"/>
```

В браузере - ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Говорят это из-за отсутствия приватного ключа. Не смог его создать и вставить.
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" - не помогает

Пробовал еще вариант

```
SSLCertificateFile="D:\domain.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile="D:\certificate.pem"
```

Но pem e меня нет, а тот, который я генерировал - вызывает

```
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

и ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR в браузере

Для чего вообще нужен файл .ca-bundle?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что я не сгенерил key и pem.

На будущее, если кому пригодится:
нужно генерировать key

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out d:\private.key 2048
```

потом на его основе запрос csr

```
openssl req -new -key d:\private.key -out d:\csr.csr
```

и на их основе pem

```
 openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in d:\csr.csr -signkey d:\private.key -out d:\certificate.pem
```

Открываете csr.csr, копируете содержимый текст и при заказе сертификата где-угодно вас попросят ввести CERTIFICATE REQUEST. Это и вставляете.
Вам присылают файл .crt. Для томката вам нужен файл .p12 который позже положится в .keystore. Делаем .p12:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in D:\domain.crt -inkey D:\private.key -out D:\server.p12 -name придумайтеАлиас -CAfile D:\certificate.pem -caname root
```

и генерируем .keystore

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass вашПароль -destkeypass вашПароль -destkeystore d:\server.keystore -srckeystore d:\server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass вашПароль -alias вашАлиас
```

Готово!

```
    <Connector port="443" 
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" 
enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" 
scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
keystoreFile="D:\server.keystore" 
SSLEnabled="true"
```

keystorePass="вашПароль"
    />

Comment: Спасибо. помог!